# How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?

Tags: wubi

I want to uninstall Ubuntu because I just don't like it...  I have windows 7 and no boot disk or anything special to uninstall, when I installed Ubuntu it said easy to uninstall and I would love to know how to actually uninstall it. Thank You.

Answer (score 17):

I will hate my answer since I always tend to tell people to use Ubuntu and give a chance (Either adapting to the new ways of using it or checking if the benefits it offers over Windows outweigh the amount of problems they face on a daily basis with Windows)

**LIVECD**
Assuming you install Ubuntu using the LiveCD (not Wubi), the fastest way is to use the Windows 7 CD/DVD. Boot from it and select "Repair your computer". Then from a repair prompt execute the following line to replace the Grub bootloader: `bootrec /fixmbr`

That will eliminate the bootable part of GRUB and reinstall the Windows 7 Boot way. After that you will have to remove the Ubuntu partition or partitions created with it. You can later merge them with Windows or install Ubuntu in case you feel you made a mistake ^^.

**WUBI**
Go to Control Panel, Uninstall a program (Vista/7) or Add/remove programs (XP), and double-click on the Ubuntu entry to automatically uninstall. [Reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation).

[image]

If this does not work, or for more information about Wubi uninstallation (or general Wubi information), follow the instructions to [manually remove Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F)

In any case I would give Ubuntu a chance, at least a 1 week test drive. Of course, remember to update everything since 12.04 has many changes that need updates after a fresh installation. I could mention the MANY benefits of using Ubuntu but I leave it to you to feel the force.

Luring Link - [Benefits of Ubuntu - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Benefits+of+Ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) (Feel the force)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I used your answer to uninstall wubi and instead install Ubuntu on its own partition :)

Comment: @chacham15 That's what I call some super uninstall cow power!

Answer (score 7):

The "easy to uninstall" part implies that you did a Wubi install, which is the easiest to remove.  A Wubi install is performed by booting Windows then inserting the Ubuntu Installation CD in the drive.  The autorun will then prompt you to start the Ubuntu Wubi installation (install inside Windows). There is also a Wubi installer that can be downloaded and run while online that installs direcly off the internet.

To Uninstall the Wubi installation from Windows 7 follow these steps:

1) Boot Windows 7

2) Open "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel

3) Find the entry for "Ubuntu"

4) Uninstall Ubuntu

Note that in step (3) above, if you can't find the listing for Ubuntu then you might have performed an install "alongside of" Windows, in which case it would have re-arranged your partitions.  It seems likely that you have done a Wubi install however.

Yes, Ubuntu is different from Windows.  If it was the same it couldn't be better, only "as good as...".  Perhaps you'll have another look sometime.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu from Windows, using Wubi, then you can simply use the normal Windows uninstall ability (add/remove programs or something similar).  But, if you installed it alongside Windows, using a normal install, then removing Ubuntu will leave you with an unbootable system, which can be fixed using a Windows repair disk, but it's not something most people know how to do - plus, you need the Windows repair disk.

So, before listening to anyone suggesting that you delete the Ubuntu partition, make sure you understand what the next steps are.

The gory details:  installing Linux alongside Windows requires that you replace the normal windows/Dos boot loader code that is in the Master Boot Record (MBR) of the disk.  This little bit of code knows to look in a certain place for the rest of what it needs, but deleting the partition with Linux will delete this code, too.  So, the MBR must be restored if you do this.

Answer (score -5):

I've never done this before, but I this is what I would do:

Step 1 - Give a second chance to Ubuntu. I this fails, go to step 2.

Step 2 - First, backup everything just in case. Secind, reboot your computer with an Ubuntu Live CD. Open the "GParted Partition Editor" to remove Ubuntu.

I can't give you detailed steps because I never did this. But I hope this answer can help you a little bit.

Comment: If he has a non-Wubi installation such as you imply, this will leave him with an unbootable system, at the grub prompt that will complain about no being able to find the configuration in /boot/grub, from the Ubuntu installation that was removed.  Bad advice.

Comment: ... and if he has a Wubi installation there is no need to run Gparted and start removing partitions...

Comment: Yes, hopefully, from the "easy to uninstall" comment, he does have the Wubi installation, but doesn't realize that it is installed like any other Windows app.  This "answer", IMHO, is worse than no answer at all.

Comment: WOW nice comments! First, I forgot about Wubi, oops. Second, I forgot about Grub, another oops. I thought about this because I've been using Gparted the last weekend. Yeah, really bad answer! It's been a bad day haha.