# How do I uninstall Wubi?

Tags: windows, wubi, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

How can I uninstall Ubuntu which I installed using Wubi without affecting my files if I have 2 OS's on 1 partition?

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall the WUBI install with the **Windows Add Remove Programs** window. The program to remove will be called `Ubuntu` and will have the Ubuntu logo

Any Files in Windows **will not be affected** but any files that are in you  Ubuntu Wubi install **MUST be saved to another place** you can save them to your windows filesystem or a USB drive.  Note: Any files created with Ubuntu *may* be unreadable by Windows.  Example `txt` files may not be completely readable `ogg` music files are unreadable, any Ubuntu system logs.

Any pictures, mp3, or video files can be transfered to Windows and be read. `ogg`files may be able to be read by Windows with the proper plug-in.

Short answer here is, you remove a Wubi install just like any other Windows program but be sure to save any important files before uninstall.