# How do I uninstall Ubuntu WUBI? What does the "Uninstall WUBI" option in the ubuntu folder do?

Tags: wubi

I installed Ubuntu with WUBI and it doesn't boot. Can I get it off my hard drive by simply deleting the ubuntu folder from drive C in Windows? What does "Uninstall WUBI" in the ubuntu folder do?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156560/how-do-i-uninstall-wubi and http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Control Panel in Windows and select **Add Remove Programs** if in Windows XP or **Programs and Features** if in Windows 7.

Select the Ubuntu entry and [uninstall](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#Uninstallation).

Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe in the Ubuntu folder does the same thing.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for the edit.