# How to uninstall ubuntu 12.04 installed from inside windows 7

Tags: 12.04, wubi, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

I installed Ubuntu running windows 7.  Now I want to remove it, want to know if i just need to uninstall it from control Panel, or is there any other way

Thanks