# how to uninstall ubuntu12.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

i have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows7 home premium in my laptop. i don't find any options to remove ubuntu. Please help me giving detailed steps on how to uninstall Ubuntu without altering windows.

thankyou

Comment: Please define "alongside". Did you use Wubi to install it from within Windows or did you boot to a CD and install it in a new partition?

Comment: or http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi

Answer (score 3):

### Installed Ubuntu inside Windows using WUBI

Run the uninstaller in **Control Panel** > **Programs and Features**or alternatively, you can run: `C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe`.

[image]

In case it fails, download [Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe).

### Installed Ubuntu on separate partition

- Boot using a LiveUSB.
- Open a new terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), then type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
```

- Press Enter.
- Then type:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

- Press Enter.
- The OS-Uninstaller window will pop out.

[image]

- Select the OS to remove and click OK.

**For more info**: Go to the following links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) from a liveCD or liveUSB disk.

[image]