# How do I remove Ubuntu without losing any data from the HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, uninstall

I've installed the newest version of Ubuntu but now I want to get back to my windows but when I reach the screen with Windows Boot Manager, like this...

[image]

(This is a screenshot from the installation guide)
...I can't use the keyboard to highlight Windows so I can't access Windows to uninstall Ubuntu.

If I use the Windows installation CD, it erases all the data on my hard disk? And if so, what other thing can I do to remove Ubuntu and without losing all my datas?

Please answer as soon as possible,
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu with WUBI? If so, please see answers on this question: [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to backup whatever you need, then just format the drive that you installed Ubuntu and Window on.

I recommend that if you wanted to use both, you should install Ubuntu after Window, since I think grub work better.