# Remove Ubuntu from Dual Boot windows 7 both in same drive

Tags: uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu as Dual BOOT with Windows 7 . I didnt had any partition for Ubuntu . Now i have to remove Ubuntu . How do i do so ??
Pls help . It is urgent

Comment: You say you don't have a separate partition for Ubuntu?  If that is the case then you did a Wubi install within windows and following the instructions below regarding deleting partitions will probably delete Windows and data.  If you did a Wubi install, see this question about removing Ubuntu wubi: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi/144255#144255

Answer (score 3):

You can go into Administrative Tools and Select Disk Management, this should bring up your partitions, delete the Ubuntu partition (in the screenshot it's e.g. the 6,33 GB partition), then you have to restore the MBR.

[image]

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) is a good forum post explaining how to do that. If you don't do this you won't be able to boot into Windows.

All this is assuming that you didn't use Wubi, if you did all you have to do is go to Add/Remove programs or whatever it is in Windows 7, find Ubuntu, and uninstall it like you would any other program.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install EasyBCD software on Windows, do to "deployment" and select Vista/7 boot loader and click on "write to MBR", then reboot. It'll restore the windows boot loader to the MBR and remove Grub.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make bootable win 7 pendrive using rufus

2.Go to diskmgmt.msc, delete the ubuntu partition and extend the drive to get more space

3.boot to win 7, select repair windows -> command prompt
enter following command:
bootrec /fixmbr

4.reboot and done

There is detailed guide here:
[https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/#:~:text=Just%20boot%20into%20Windows%20and,loader%20entry%20from%20your%20computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/#:%7E:text=Just%20boot%20into%20Windows%20and,loader%20entry%20from%20your%20computer).