# how do I uninstall Ubuntu, when the traditional ways fail?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

I want to remove Ubuntu from my computer, and I cant figure out how to do it. I have tried to go to uninstall programs, and did not find it on the list, and the file uninstaller-wubi does nothing. what do I do?

Comment: @Atem18 the question you think it is a dupe of does not cover Wubi installations...

Answer (score 0):

If you have already gone to Start > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features and Ubuntu not listed there , probably something went wrong with the uninstall. (or install)

One suggestion is to Install it again and try to Uninstall it (again).

Another suggestion might be to correct the boot-loader (if the issue is in boot-loader "Ubuntu" entry comes up) . Correct the boot-loader with a CD/DVD of Windows Version you have , by "Repair" option.

Thanks