# Uninstall Windows 7 from ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have installed ubuntu inside windows 7 via wubi. How do i uninstall windows 7, keeping ubuntu as my primary OS?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/144237/62483

Comment: Note that the duplicate *is* partially valid, however wubi installs *within* Windows' partition, not as a standalone installation.  Back up the files, then install for a normal dual-boot and copy your files back in.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't, at least not easily.  Wubi's designed to install Ubuntu inside the Windows partition in what is called a loopback file.  Essentially, when Ubuntu boots, first the kernel mounts the Win7 NTFS partition, then looks for the file that contains the Ubuntu file system and "pivots" onto it.  The cleanest way to get rid of Windows would be to reinstall without using Wubi.

Of course, technically it would be *possible* to manually repartition, copy everything from the loopback filesystem, delete Windows, repartition *again*, install the bootloader, etc.  But I think that route would be nothing but a trail of tears for anyone except maybe Linus Torvalds ;).

Don't forget to back up your data!

Comment: I should add that Ubuntu has pretty extensive sync capability with Ubuntu One.  You can even back up your installed list of applications in the Software Center; this could potentially save you a lot of work after reinstalling!