# How to remove WUBI installed Ubuntu without affecting Windows files?

Tags: 11.04, wubi, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

I have Windows 7 in my laptop with that I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 using WUBI with partition.

Now I want to remove Ubuntu from my laptop without affecting my Windows files and data. Is there any effective way to do this?