# How can I uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 if I installed it with the Windows installer?

Tags: 12.10, windows, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi)

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 but I want to know before how can I uninstall it and return only to windows and don't have Ubuntu and Windows together.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to 
`My computer > Uninstall or change a program` 
& find ubuntu installer and uninstall that.
or
Go to: `Control Panel> Uninstall a program`

Answer (score 0):

This guide might help you to [uninstall ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.