# How do I switch back and uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I followed the instructions and downloaded the program, installed, restarted and I was brought to the Linux startup page. I was then panicking, how the hell do I switch back to Windows? Why can't I access the local drive I used to have?

I gave in and I don't want Ubuntu anymore. How do I switch back and uninstall Ubuntu?

I'm using a laptop. Sorry if you have bad impressions on me because I only used Ubuntu for a game.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows and ubuntu you can select windows on startup and even hide that purple operating system screen you get a startup.
If you don't have Windows anymore well.. reinstall Windows (and delete the partitions the windows installer will display as "unknown").