# Can't install either 12.04 or 13.04 off a flash drive

Tags: flash, drive

I've used two different programmes for creating a flash drive I can boot from, but each time I get the same message after choosing to boot Ubuntu that says that a certain file is missing or corrupted:

```
file: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
status: 0xc000007b
```

I'm running the x64 version of Windows 8 on a laptop I got not three months ago.

Any suggestions as to what to do?

Answer (score 0):

[How can I fix ubuntu winboot wubildr.mbr missing error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342898/how-can-i-fix-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-missing-error) shows this involves the WUBI install of Ubuntu, but that won't boot from a flash drive. Suggest you create a non-WUBi version instead.