# Sony Vaio - Boot Error from USB Stick

Tags: boot, usb, vaio, sony

I have Sony Vaio with Inte i3 Processor - 2.27 GHz processor and 3 GB RAM, 64 bit with Windows 7, operating system, trying to replace with Ubuntu

Created USB with instructions as in below link
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Getting boot error, when tried to boot from external device. Used SanDisk 32 GB flash drive.

Comment: Do you plan to use dual boot? Before creating a live-usb with rufus you  need to figure out first if you need to be using MBR+BIOS-boot or GPT+UEFI-boot. See here: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/644901/booting-a-sony-vaio-computer-running-windows-8-1-in-ubuntu-from-a-usb-drive?rq=1

Comment: I am planning to use just Ubuntu and I don't need Windows 7 - I am new to Linux and new to Sysadmin side of things- I work in Windows environment and database development side - so I am fine with whatever works on my machine

Comment: In that case, the easiest way to go would be going into your bios, making sure you disable UEFI and stick to BIOS boot mode, then configure rufus for MBR/BIOS when creating your live-usb.

Comment: yes, I used same settings (MBR/BIOS) as in this - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3 page. except cluster size it was defaulted to 32 KB usb live creation is fine and I disabled UEFI - the option in Sony Vaio is External Boot - enable.

After it goes into boot - just gets "Boot error" - no other info

Comment: one more thing I think of is, currently my disk is partitioned to 3 drives, but c drive currently has over 100 GB free - does partitioning matter ?

Comment: I think I figured I had to enable internal virtualization technology option enabled - thank you very much for your responses

Comment: Virtualization is only needed if you run linux under a virtual machine on top of Windows (like vmware or virtualbox). If you are running it directly on the laptop it has no effect.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe that laptop is configured not to overwrite windows OS that's why I had to enable that option. I have to check if it actually overwrote Windows OS.