# Booting problems

Tags: boot, wubi

I installed `Ubuntu` on my hard drive using `wubi.exe`. When I went to boot it I got a message:

```
Windows tried to start. A recent hardware or software might be the cause.
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mdr
Status: 0xc000000e

Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the app is missing or corrupt.
```

Comment: please refer [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/winload-exe-missing-corrupt/)... and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342898/how-can-i-fix-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-missing-error)

Answer (score 0):

Wubi method is outdated, Try [UNetbootin.exe](http://unetbootin.github.io/)
Read the documentation and follow directions for the [frugal](http://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/) method if you don't have a working CD drive but still have a working USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Open command prompt as administator.
- type `bcdedit` then press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Scroll down to **Real-mode boot Sector**
- Copy code corresponding to `identifier`
- Now type `bcdedit /delete <[identifier code you copied]>` then <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Now restart.

<sub>source [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_92aKSu4Es)</sub>