# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs, can fix/login but then after reboot it hangs again. Have bootscript/details. Wubi issue?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

Setup: Dual boot, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. 'Boot info summary' shown below.

Issue: I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) and then updated software. On reboot, the boot sequence exits to grub rescue terminal and reports error: "error: no such device...  Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>"

If I reboot, enter the BIOS menu and then "exit and disgard any changes", then (instead of hanging) the Grub2 menu appears (!) and can then login normally to Ubuntu (or Windows.) Can also use Boot Repair Live CD to fix it. However, on reboot the same issue arises. So whilst there is a temporary workaround, it is a rubbish solution and belies future problems with updates. Had 5 days of reboots. Please help newbie.

Note: Root=sdb5. Boot locations sda1 & sdb1. Bootscrip log identifies wubildr and wubildr.mbr in sda2/sdb2 (mbr/boots). There is a wubildr file in the C: drive 'though (although not an executable/binary).

Question: Is the error due to an issue with 'mounting of devices', dual-boot/wubi/mbr, 'boot location' or other issue? If so, how to fix? Will upgrade to 15.04 / 16.04 help? I can't be the first person to have this issue, perhaps you can forward a link to an existing solution.

History: Ubuntu is not installed on Windows, probably was before (can't remember.) PC created with Win7 / Ubuntu (12.04) dual boot. Changing partitions bricked Ubuntu. So, Ubuntu partition re-formatted, and re-installed using Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD. Grub2 issues encountered.  "bootrec/fixmbr" && "bootrec/fixboot" have been utilised, using Windows Repair Live CD, to fix mbr. Boot Repair Live CD used to repair Grub2.

Note: NVIDIA NVS300 graphics card installed & dual display works. Also, GeForce GTX 970 graphics card installed for Cuda parallel processing.

```
                 Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /wubildr /wubildr.mbr

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sdb1 
                       and looks at sector 1795665720 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 112 for . No errors found in the Boot 
                       Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /wubildr

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   234,438,655   234,231,808   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048 1,677,723,647 1,677,721,600   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdb2       1,843,202,048 1,953,519,615   110,317,568   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdb3       1,677,725,694 1,843,202,047   165,476,354   5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1,677,725,696 1,809,750,015   132,024,320  83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       1,809,752,064 1,843,202,047    33,449,984  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        4C56283856282564                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        9A2C2C492C2C22AD                       ntfs       
/dev/sdb1        26BE725CBE722509                       ntfs       Storage
/dev/sdb2        06DCACD5DCACC073                       ntfs       Backup
/dev/sdb5        27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sdb5        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdb5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic root=UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-93-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-93-generic-advanced-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-93-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic root=UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-93-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-93-generic-recovery-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-93-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic root=UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-4C56283856282564' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  4C56283856282564
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4C56283856282564
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-9A2C2C492C2C22AD' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  9A2C2C492C2C22AD
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9A2C2C492C2C22AD
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sdb5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=27bd3aa5-7686-446e-93d4-4e82f609d707 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
#UUID=00c62221-355c-4f44-aa9f-64d4777c3bca none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-Hy9WmV4t/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Also, previously, tried: sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/grub /dev/sdb  . Later used Boot Repair Live CD to install grub to both sda & sdb.

Comment: chris@chris-uk:~$ mount
/dev/sdb5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)

Comment: none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/home/chris/.Private on /home/chris type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=64e7ab672841c56e,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=7247360350d85927)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse

Comment: (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chris)

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark but have you tried

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Your grub and linux are on sdb but your boot is on sda.

Normal grub setup changes are done on sdb but update grub affects sdb only. You need the above command to make the changes on sdb to the boot grub image on sda (boot drive) too.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Fair shout, yep, managed to effect that using Boot Repair (Advanced options) which gave option to install grub on both sda and sdb. See solution which worked for me in the end below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the grub2 bootloader to work (consistently)!

P.S. No, wubi was not the issue, wubi is fine. Turning on (U)EFI settings in the BIOS menu / executing Grub2 bootloader in (U)EFI mode were the issue.

Solution utilised:

' Boot a live CD-R or USB flash drive in EFI mode and run Boot Repair. This should get GRUB up and running with Windows detected. The trick is forcing an EFI-mode boot of a live CD. You may need to play with your firmware's boot options. Typically, hitting a function key (which one varies) produces a boot menu, and you should select the one for your live CD that mentions "EFI" or "UEFI." '

Summary explanation:

'...the problem that you've got a mixed-mode installation -- Windows is booting in EFI mode, whereas Linux is set up to boot in BIOS mode. This can be awkward at best, so you should probably convert Linux to boot in EFI mode.'

Thanks go to Rob Smith (et al). Above quotations are copy-pasted from: 
[How can I fix ubuntu winboot wubildr.mbr missing error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342898/how-can-i-fix-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-missing-error)